# Can't Access Column Default Values in Library created from a Template

Tags: document-library

Column Default Values on a library created from a library template cannot be accessed. Is there a way to create a library, add folders and CDVs to it, save it as a template, and have it work? My steps are below:

1. Create a library app

2.a.  Add a content type to it

2b.  Add folders to your library.

3. Add Column Default Values to a folder or folders (I added term store terms to a few folders on mine)
4. Save document library as a template in library settings
5. Click include content to get the folders included in template
6. Go to a different site within same collection in SharePoint
7. Click gear, add an app
8. Search for the template you just created, create app
9. go to new library's settings
10. Click Column Default Values, receive Error

Does anyone know why this happens or how to workaround? There's a Microsoft Community [post](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/215398.aspx) about it, but no answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you define Column Default Settings for a Library or folder, this information is included in any list template that you save on this basis. However, when instantiating a new library from your list template, the Defaults you have entered previously remain linked to the OLD (original) library. So, the reference isn't updated to match the newly created library. IMO, this is a bug in SharePoint (both SharePoint 2010 an SharePoint 2013).

You can verify and fix this as follows:

1. Open your Web in SharePoint Designer
2. Using "All Files", navigate to the "Forms" folder of the library you created based on your template
3. Open the file "**client_LocationBasedDefaults.html**"
4. find the reference to your original library and replace that path with the correct one
5. Save the file

-> Now you will be able to access the Defaults page in your library Settings.

Unfortunately, you need to go through these steps for every library that you have created based on your list template.